# Django Query: filtering Decimal('NaN') value?

Tags: django, django-queryset

This is my model:

```
class DailyPrice(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField()

    close = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=15,
        decimal_places=2,
    )
```

I'd like to get all `DailyPrice` objects whose `close` field is `Decimal('NaN')`.

(I can check `Decimal('NaN')` below query example)

```
>> DailyPrice.objects.last().close
Decimal('NaN')
```

What I tried is

`DailyPrice.objects.filter(close__isnull=True)`

But it doesn't return anything....

How can I implement this?

Comment: your django version ?

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool it's 1.11

Comment: try to set default value of Decimal Field and then try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Decimal('NaN')` as filtered value:

```
import decimal

DailyPrice.objects.filter(close=decimal.Decimal('NaN'))
```